# Conditional Probability with Poisson's variable

Tags: statistics

I've been having difficulty with the following problem.

A driver is circling a parking lot searching for a parking space. The parking spaces distribute in a poisson's distribution of λ=0.3.

Knowing that the driver has found a parking space, what's the probability that that would be the only parking space?

I tried approaching the problem via conditional probability saying that $P(s=1|s>=1)$ but I can't figure out what to do next.

Thank you.

Comment: Where are you getting stuck? Yes you are right that we need to find conditional probability and that is $\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}. P(B)$ is unconditional probability of him finding a spot which is nothing but $1$ minus probability of him not finding a spot. Can you get that? That is your denominator. Then we can find $P(A \cap B)$. $A$ is the event of him finding a spot and that being the only one.

Comment: The probability of him finding a spot is 0.26 to my calculation.My problem is how do I compute P(A∩B)  in this case?

Comment: Yes you are correct on your denominator. Now for $P(A \cap B)$, you want him to find a spot and that to be the only one which is $P(A = 1) = \lambda^1 \, e^{-\lambda} / 1!$.

Comment: If $A$ is the event of there being only one spot and $B$ is the event of him finding a spot. The intersection of two is nothing but $P(A)$  in this case as $A$ is a subset of $B$, if that is your confusion.

Comment: so in fact I get $P(s=1)/P(s>=1)$ which gives me $e^-0.3*0.3/(1-e^-0.3)=0.857$ correct?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: you're the best thank's a lot

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$P(S|S>0)=\frac{1}{1-e^{-0.3}}\frac{e^{-0.3}0.3^s}{s!}$$

Thus

$$P(S=1|S>0)=\frac{0.3}{e^{0.3}-1}\approx 85.75\%$$

Comment: how did you get there? what's the meaning of the argument on the left and how do I use it with S>=1? thank you

Comment: @MisheMitasek : the argument on the left is a normalizing constant. Given that the rv is defined in $\{1,2,3,...\}$ the cumulative probability is $1-e^{-0.3}$. In the meantime, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future